One goes to clubs, the other reads a book
Looking for a movie with two young males. They're friends but one is going out while the other keeps reading a book. They mention it multiple times. I think the book is about a story where things happen in half of the book, and nothing in the other half. It might be a thriller or horror movie, I'm not sure. I've seen it about 15 years ago.
edit: The way of life of the two characters refer to the book. I remember the guy going out telling the other the book must be boring when nothing happens on the half. And the pace is really slow when we see the reader, much faster when we see the other. Then, obviously, the twist of the movie is when something happens to the reader. I don't know what, but the other guy becomes much less interesting.
I think the reader spends most of his time guarding the entrance of some building in a booth (where he reads). The ambiance is rather gloomy there, picture is dark. I think it's mostly dark wooden furniture. He refuses to follow his friend going out. Both might be in their early 20s
I think it was an american movie, set in current time about 15-20 years ago (no mentions of internet or smartphones probably ...). Though I probably saw it in french language (dubbed) at the time. Based on timing of my movie sources at that time, it must have had an international DVD release around 99 or 2000.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
